# ggplot tile line between cells

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I am using ggplot and `geom_tile` to form heatmaps. And I wish to insert some faint lines between the cells.

For example:

My ggplot `geom_tile` heatmap:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
data("iris")
x = melt(cor(iris[,1:4]))
ggplot(data=x,aes(Var1,Var2,fill=value)) + geom_tile() # No line between the cells
```

What I desire (from d3heatmap package in R)

```
library(d3heatmap)
data("iris")
x = cor(iris[,1:4])
d3heatmap(cor(iris[,1:4]),Rowv = F,Colv = F) #There is a faint line between the cells
```

(Sorry can't post any pictures)
Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just add `color = "gray"` to your geom_tile

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
data("iris")
x = melt(cor(iris[,1:4]))
ggplot(data=x,aes(Var1,Var2,fill=value)) + 
  geom_tile(color = "gray")
```

Will give you this figure with lines between the tiles:[image]

You can play with `size` to make the lines bigger or smaller , and/or use `color = white`.

Comment: Hi! thanks for sharing. I'm wondering if there are any ways to set particular cell to some color? Like I want Sepal.Length and  Sepal.width to be "red".

Comment: @jimmy15923 Set the data, not the cell. Or ask it as a new question.