# How to plot the variant circular bar chart in r with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graph

I want to plot a picture like this but I don't know how to plot it with R. I saw a tutorial on this [website](https://www.data-to-viz.com/graph/circularbarplot.html) but this is not what I needed. It is like a circular bar chart except that, in the picture below every bar is not a single value but a series value denote different incidence in a different year.

In the picture below is the template.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

My fake data:

```
structure(list(year = c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2010, 
2011, 2012, 2010, 2011, 2012), disease = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4), group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), incidence = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1, 0.3, 
0.2, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.3)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

[image]

Comment: Or is it a circular heatmap?

Comment: Hi @zhiweili, I think it helps if you provide a sample data. I think it is a bit borderline whether this question should be closed. Also I think you should explain what you would like to see, i.e is it just a simple circular heatmap or with other features. These details help.

Comment: To me, this is a valid question because there is no current package in ggplot2 to do a circular heatmap like the OP described

Comment: Hi @StupidWolf, my friend. Sorry, I forget to post my fake data. Now I edit my question. This picture was from there[https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7114954/]. It shows the description of different infectious disease incidence at different years with the circular heatmap. And I want to mimic his graph in my data.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a circular heatmap.. most likely there are packages for doing it. Below is like a quick attempt in ggplot2 to do it:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

mat = matrix(runif(200),10,20)
colnames(mat) = paste0("col",1:ncol(mat))
rownames(mat) = paste0("row",1:nrow(mat))
```

Suppose `mat` is our matrix, then we pivot long and preserve the row and column orders in factor:

```
df = data.frame(mat) %>% 
rownames_to_column("row") %>% 
pivot_longer(-row) %>%
mutate(name=factor(name,levels=colnames(mat)),
row=factor(row,levels=rownames(mat)))
```

Then we plot, below I added another column to add the row names annotation:

```
row_num = length(levels(df$row))

g = ggplot(df,aes(x=name,y=as.numeric(row),fill=value)) + 
xlim(c("",colnames(mat))) + ylim(c(-row_num/1.5,row_num+1))+
geom_tile()+ ylab("")+
annotate(x="",y=1:row_num,label=levels(df$row),size=2.5,geom="text")
```

[image]

So you have a "elevated" heatmap. And the first column is the label. The purpose is to now wrap this and form the circular heatmap:

```
g + coord_polar(start=-0.15) + theme_bw() + 
theme(legend.position = c(0.5, 0.5),legend.key.size = unit(0.2, "cm"))
```

[image]

Comment: This is a good answer. BTW, my friend, do you know how to crimp the legend and put it in the middle of the plot just as the template I posted.

Comment: edited answer. you use legend.position in theme(), the numbers are relative to the plot, so 0.5,0.5 means center.. i don't know how to make the legend circular too

Comment: That's enough，thanks a lot, this really helps me a lot!

Comment: Hi, my friend, bother you again, I also have another question. I want to add black box around every cell. I tried add `color = 'black'` both inside or outside `aes()` just like this:`ggplot(df,aes(x=name,y=as.numeric(row),fill=value, color = 'black'))` (This code add orange box around every cell and add another legend). `ggplot(df,aes(x=name,y=as.numeric(row),fill=value), color = 'black')` (This code nothing change the plot). Both the situation were not my expectation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32665431/ggplot-tile-line-between-cells, you got to call it within geom_tile(color="black")

Comment: Hello quick question - how can you specify the width of the labelling column?