# How to add a continuous line with geom_line in plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

As the title, I had a fake data:

```
data <-
structure(list(year = c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2010, 
2011, 2012, 2010, 2011, 2012), disease = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4), group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), incidence = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1, 0.3, 
0.2, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.3)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to draw a line to show different group (`disease 1` and `disease 2` belong to `group A` with one color, `disease 3` and `disease 4` belong to `group B` with another color), But the line draw to the year labels not to the last category and also I can not set `fill` and `color` in `geom_segment`:

```
data <- data %>% mutate(disease = as.factor(disease), group =  as.factor(group))
data %>% ggplot(aes(x = disease, y = year, fill= incidence) ) + 
  geom_tile(color = 'black')+ ylab("") + xlab("") +
  xlim(c("",unique(data$disease))) + 
  ylim(c(2005,2012+1)) + 
  annotate(x="",y=2010:2012,label=2010:2012,size=2.5,geom="text")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(
    axis.line = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank()
    
  ) + 
 geom_segment(aes(x = as.numeric(disease)+0.5, xend = as.numeric(disease)-0.5,
                 y = 2009, yend = 2009, group = group, fill = group), size = 2, color = 'black')
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Why not use facetting?

Comment: @PaulvanOppen. Because there are many groups in my real data and I want to draw a circular heatmap. This is just a part of my code. You can see the my expected plot at here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62556246/how-to-plot-the-variant-circular-bar-chart-in-r-with-ggplot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply replace `geom_line` by `geom_segment`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data) + 
  geom_tile(aes(x = disease, y = year, fill= incidence), color = 'black') +
  geom_segment(aes(x = disease - 0.5, xend = disease + 0.5, y = 2009, yend = 2009, group = group, color = group)) +
  ylab("") + 
  xlab("") +
  xlim(c(1:4,"")) + 
  ylim(c(2005,2012+1)) + 
  annotate(x="",y=2010:2012,label=2010:2012,size=2.5,geom="text")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(
    axis.line = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank()
    
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works. But I also have some problems and I update my question. 1) In my real data, `disease` is a factor and the year labels were on the left, so the new code in the question was closer to my situation. The result is not my expected. Because it draws to the labels not to the last category. 2) I want to use `fill = group` within `aes()` and `color = black` without `aes()` in `geom_segment()` but failed. Is there a way to set `fill` and `color` meanwhile in `geom_segment()`?

Comment: Okay. I see.1)  The `factor` is not an issue. In that case convert to numeric. And set the labels via `scale_x_continuous(labels = c(...))`. But I'm not sure whether geom_segment will work for the kind of cirular plot you are trying to achieve. 2) geom_segment or geom_line have no fill aesthetic. If you want a fill you can try geom_rect

Comment: Thanks a lot and there is just one question left : Why the line draw to year labels not to the last category.

Comment: 1) Concerning the fill. geom_rect will not work easily as you already have a fill scale. 2) Simply add + 1 in geom_segemnt i.e. `as.numeric(disease) + 1` to shift the starting and end point one category to the right.

Comment: ... just in case I meant `as.numeric(disease) + 1 +/- 0.5`. (;